# Laravel validation digits

Tags: php, laravel

I have a rule:

```
'price' => 'required|numeric|digits:8,13'
```

I need allow only 8 digits or 13 digits on validation. My code is not working. If I write 8 digits, then validation say that I need write 13 digits. How I can fix it?

Comment: Just going by a google search, would it not be `digits_between`? Or 2 digits validators?

Comment: @Jonnix No. Then this allow write 9 digits, 10, 11.. e.t.c I need allow only 8 and 13!

Comment: Does Laravel validation support `or` validators that would let you use 2 `digits` clauses? Otherwise you could write your own simple one.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson 5.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can have a regex rule to mimic 8 digits or 13 digits.

```
'price' => array(
             'required',
             'numeric',
             'regex:/^(\d{8}|\d{13})$/',
           )
```

Comment: `preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found` why??

Comment: @Dronax I fixed it. We need to put validation rules in an array when we have a `|` pipe character matching with the `|` used to mention several rules to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom validation for your need. 
Check laravel documentation here. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation

```
Validator::extend('custom_rule_name',function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
  return  $value == 13 || $value == 8;
});
```

Comment: .. or just `return ($value == 13 || $value == 8)`

Comment: I don't need `strlen` for check it?

Comment: @Dronax yes your just checking if the value is equal to 13 or 8
'price' => 'required|numeric|custom_rule_name'

Answer (score 0):

You need a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules). The pass function would be:

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    $digits = strlen((string)$value);
    return $digits === 8 || $digits === 13;
}
```

Comment: No. Then this allow write 9 digits, 10, 11.. e.t.c I need allow only 8 and 13!

Comment: You mean maybe 8 **or** 13 ?

Comment: Yes. Only 8 or 13, without 9,10,11,12

Comment: By the way, I think a 13 digits number is out of the integer range. http://au2.php.net/manual/es/language.types.integer.php

Comment: You of course) Thanks, I change type integer to numeric

Comment: And referring to your original question, you would have to create create a custom validation rule that will check if the length or the input is 8 or 13. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: `count(strlen(...))` ?? Are you sure? ;)

Comment: Ops! My bad! Thanks!